# Unhandled promise rejection connecting to mongodb.com

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, heroku

I have a local angular project, connecting to my mongodb, but when trying to connect to a remote one on mongodb.com, I get unhandled promise exceptions:

```
(node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: err is not defined at mongoose.connect.then.catch (/app/app.js:27:26) 

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It looks to be an issue with this code, but I am unsure what to change, since this works locally. When running on heroku, I get the error.

```
// Map global promise - get rid of warning
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
// Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-cx2dj.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true", {
    useNewUrlParser: true
})
.then(() => console.log('MongoDb Connected...'))
.catch(() => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Different versions of Node? Also you'll only see that if there *is* an error connecting, have you invoked that locally?

Comment: Ah I see. If I break the connection to mongodb locally, I do get that error. I am not sure why I can connect locally but not through Heroku though.

Comment: If you actually add `err` to the `.catch` callback parameters, you might see more information.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am new to angular and missed this mistake. Adding the missing reference to err told me an error I could debug better. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe, I managed to add a reference to `err`. This then showed me the connection error:

```
MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster closed
```

It looks like I needed to whitelist the ip of my heroku instance by going to the security tab in my mongodb cluster.